# Spring Data with ReactiveMongoRepository: generic saving

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I would like to save some documents with the value containing a generic. And I constantly receive a `StackOferflowError`.

Here is a fragment of my model class

```
data class MyDocument {
    val errors: List<SomeError> = emptyList()
}
```

SomeError is in interface that should be implemented by different types of errors including ValidationError

```
interface SomeError

data class ValidationError<T: Any>(val objectType: KClass<T>, val objectId: String) : SomeError
```

I am trying to save my object with non-empty list of errors (using ReactiveMongoRespoitory):

```
myDocumentRepository.save(MyDocument(
     errors = listOf( 
     ValidationError<MyDocument>(objectType = MyDocument::class, objectId = "somedoc")) //as SomeError did not help
))
```

Do you know how I can correct it?

This is a psrt of the Stack trace:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:624)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:510)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:780)
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.resolveType(TypeDiscoverer.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.calculateTypeVariables(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:269)
```

Comment: I find it unlikely that a stack overflow is caused by a query. Could you post a few of the I assume repeating lines of the stack trace?

Comment: @JensSchauder you are right: I just cannot add a field with generic value

Comment: What does that mean? So far the question was about querying. Where are you adding a "generic value"?

Comment: you were right: it is not a question of quering

Comment: Then please either update the question or delete it so others don't waste time trying to answer it.

Comment: @JensSchauder done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient

data class ValidationError private constructor(
  private val type: String,
  val objectId: String
) : SomeError {
  constructor(type: KClass<*>, objectId: String) : this(type.qualifiedName!!, objectId)

  @delegate:Transient
  val objectType by lazy {
    this.javaClass.classLoader.loadClass(type).kotlin
  }
}
```

Store KClass internally as fully qualified name.